# Berkshelf install --except option not working

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, berkshelf

I'm using following command to install my cookbook dependencies. But the tomcat-all cookbook still gets installed by berkshelf.

```
berks install -e tomcat-all -b ./cookbooks/mfs-tomcat/Berksfile
```

What am I doing wrong here? My berkshelf version installed is 3.2.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined a group called "tomcat-all" within your Berkshelf file? See the documentation http://berkshelf.com/#groups

Comment: Yes @mark-oconnor I have. Actually `berks install --only tomcat-all -b ./cookbooks/mfs-tomcat/Berksfile` works without any issue.

Comment: Could "tomcat-all" be a dependency of one of the other cookbooks? That might explain why it still gets pulled down.

Comment: Thanks Mark for pointing that out. But this is the only cookbook that has a dependency to 'tomcat-all'. I checked twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to reset@Chef.io.

The problem was the metadata.rb file of my mfs-tomcat cookbook also had the dependency for 'tomcat-all' cookbook.
Since metadata.rb has a higher precedence it overrides the groups I have created in Berksfile.
Thanks @mark-oconnor also for helping out.